# Blinn Material in Maya 2014

Tags: 3d, maya

Is Blinn material from rendering ribbon implemented only in spherical objects and not to objects like prism,cubes etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Blinn shader is just a regular shader. It can be applied to any 'shape' of object.